# Indexed Javascript Parse Promise Loops

Tags: javascript, loops, parse-platform, promise

I am trying to use the values given by class 1 to find more values in class 2 related to class 1's values. I was going to do this by looping the value of k, however, it seem no matter where I put the loop, it only uses the final value of k. Can anyone tell me how to deal with a necessity for indices when dealing with promises? I am new to both promises and parse. Edit: IF bracket was misplaced.

```
var Class1 = Parse.Object.extend("Class1");
var Class2 = Parse.Object.extend("Class2");

Parse.Promise.as().then(function () {

  var query = new Parse.Query(Class1);
  return query.find()

  }).then(function (class1IDs) {
    for (var k = 0; k < class1IDs.length; k++) {

      var class1IDEntry = class1IDs[k];
      var class1ID = class1IDEntry.id;

      Parse.Promise.as().then(function () {
        var class1 = new Class1();
        class1.id = class1ID;

        var query = new Parse.Query(Class2); //
        query.equalTo("class1", class1);
        return query.find()

      }).then(function (class2IDs) {
        var stuff;
      });
    }

  }).then(function() {
    done();
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    done(new Error(error));
  });
});
```

Comment: I assume this is because promises are asynchronous? If so, is there a way to stop one end while another moves forward for a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to wait for all the promises created inside the for loop to finish, before the `done()` call right - should the queries inside the loop run in series or parallel? The other issue you have is due to asynchronous nature of the code, all `class1.id = class1ID` will have `class1ID` of the last item in `class1IDs` (as you suspect)

Run through class1IDs in series

```
var Class1 = Parse.Object.extend("Class1");
var Class2 = Parse.Object.extend("Class2");

Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Class1);
    return query.find()
}).then(function(class1IDs) {
    return class1IDs.reduce(function(promise, class1IDEntry) {
        var class1ID = class1IDEntry.id;
        var class1 = new Class1();
        class1.id = class1ID;
        var query = new Parse.Query(Class2); //
        query.equalTo("class1", class1);
        return promise.then(function() {
            return query.find();
        }).then(function(class2IDs) {
            var stuff;
        });
    }, Parse.Promise.as());
}).then(function() {
    done();
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    done(new Error(error));
});
```

Run through class1IDs in parallel

```
var Class1 = Parse.Object.extend("Class1");
var Class2 = Parse.Object.extend("Class2");

Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Class1);
    return query.find()
}).then(function(class1IDs) {
    return Parse.Promise.when.apply(null, class1IDs.map(function(class1IDEntry) {
        var class1ID = class1IDEntry.id;
        var class1 = new Class1();
        class1.id = class1ID;
        var query = new Parse.Query(Class2); //
        query.equalTo("class1", class1);
        return query.find()
        .then(function(class2IDs) {
            var stuff;
        });
    }));
}).then(function() {
    done();
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    done(new Error(error));
});
```